# DiffInDays in Carbon php

Tags: php, php-carbon

I'm trying to use Carbon PHP, the thing is I'm new at it and I'm not sure to know how to proceed. I want to get the number of days in a month, so I create a Carbon instance to get the 1st day of the month. I added a month to it and try to get the difference with diffInDays, but it returns me 0.
I tried lots of things but I can't solve this problem. Do you guys have an idea?

Here is the code.

```
$month = intval($_GET['month'], 10);
$year = intval($_GET['year'], 10);


$monthToEvaluate = Carbon::create($year, $month, 1, 0, 0); //It returns a Carbon Instance with the correct date
$monthAfter = $monthToEvaluate->addMonth(); //It returns a Carbon Instance with the correct date too

echo $monthAfter->diffInDays($monthToEvaluate, false); //var_dump of this returns int(0)
```

Comment: `$monthToEvaluate->addMonth();` modifies `$monthToEvaluate`.... it isn't immutable, so `$monthToEvaluate` and `$monthAfter` will be the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way, See more at http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

```
$monthToEvaluate = Carbon::create($year, $month, 1, 0, 0);
echo $monthToEvaluate->diffInDays($monthToEvaluate->copy()->addMonth());
```